# Installation prefix of "KF5I18n" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: cmake, kde-plasma

When installing the following package with homebrew
`brew install kde-mac/kde/kf5-kio`

I get a series of installation errors

Primarily the following:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/x/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kf5-kconfigwidgets/01.cmake:
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5I18n"
  (requested version 5.111.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5I18nConfig.cmake
    kf5i18n-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5I18n" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5I18n_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5I18n" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I have seen similar articles with the same error for other installations, however, I think this package is the root problem. Is there a solution to installation the Kf5 packages?

EDIT:

Upon checking my `cmake` folder in `/user/local` I recognise it has the folder `KF6I18n`, rather than `KF5I18n`, I wonder whether this is causing the issue, whether I have to downgrade this somehow?
This goes the same for the folder `ki18n`, it instead had the +6 version, rather than +5. I wonder whether this can be modified in an installation file of some sort?